# Ubuntu 20.04 alongside Windows 10 - what are all these partitions for?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

Recently I installed Ubuntu 20.04 (with GRUB bootloader) alongside Windows 10 on Dell Inspiron N5110 (previously upgraded from win7). When installing I chose the simple partitioning tool on the Ubuntu installer instead of doing it manually, and allocated 300GB to windows and 199GB to ubuntu. However when I open disks there are several partitions and I want to know what these are for, and whether I can delete them and add to the main two partitions.

[These are my partitions - stackexchange wont let me embed images yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkYeL.png)

Apart from the 300GB NTFS for windows and the 198GB ext4 for ubuntu, there are three other partitions. The 105MB is system reserved for windows, which I know I can't delete. However within /dev/sda4 there is also an 537MB EFI partition in FAT32 - do I need this even if I'm only using legacy BIOS and MBR? Also what is the purpose of the 520MB NTFS partition if Windows already has the 105MB system reserved?

Comment: You might want to ask yourself if you want to recover this space at all since it’s only about 0.2% of the drive and any change is not without risk. The 537 MB partition looks like an unused EFI partition which you don’t need. The other small partition is possibly an EFI partition created by a previous Windows install but we cannot see enough of it to be sure. If you do want to recover this space make sure you backup your data and be prepared to fix a broken grub.